# Installed Ubuntu in an external drive connecting with USB 3.0. Ubuntu 16.04.1 wouldn't boot after installation

Tags: 16.04, boot, usb, hard-drive, lockup

I have 1 M.2 SSD, and 1 2.5in SSD on my laptop. Attaching the 1TB 2.5in HDD in Syba SY-ENC25054 USB 3.0 to SATA 2.5" Hard Drive External Enclosure Case

Windows 10 is installed on the first drive. The second drive does more of data storing function for virtual machines. 
I have this 1TB HDD inserted into the case and was successful at installing Ubuntu 16.04.1 on that drive. Using a USB drive.
I configured the drive with

```
1GB ext4 for "\boot"

20GB "swap"

40GB ext4 for "\"

400GB ext4 for "\home"
```

the rest 400GB or so to FAT32

After selecting the boot option from bios.
This error message shows up shortly.

```
kernel bug soft lockup - cpu#0 stuck for 22s
```

the cpu# varies from time to time.

I have the MSI GL62 6QF with i7-6700HQ and gtx960M, 12GB DDR4.

I tired to switch speedstep, hyperthreading, and c-state on and off in all combinations. But the problem still cant be solved.

Searched up other people's post, some fixed by removing Nvidia graphics card, some turned USB setting from 3.0 to 2.0 in a virtual machine.
Tried both my USB 3.0 and 2.0 ports, the problem always pop up.

Any help will be appreciated greatly.

Answer (score 0):

So one of the more common causes of this is that the CPU is ever so slightly unstable, needing just a tad more `vCore` voltage.

What's causing the voltage to be less than what's needed could be caused by many different things:

- A bad power supply or battery that's not capable of keeping up with the power demand
- A bad voltage regulator on the motherboard
- Capacitors that have gone bad
- Some other hardware failure

---

Now admittedly, it would seem suspicious that Windows is running fine if you have had a hardware failure. Therefore I suggest:

Run Prime95 stress test in Windows (with the maximum heat and FPU stress configuration) and see if it gives you any errors after letting it run for about 30 minutes. **Please note:** it would be prudent to do this with a CPU temperature monitor open, as Prime 95 does have the ability to overheat your machine

If Prime95 gives you errors, then you know you have a hardware failure on hand. If not, then then it's still very helpful to eliminate hardware failure as a potential problem cause.

One other thing you might try is to install Ubuntu 17.10 instead, as it contains a newer kernel which could have potentially fixed the error.